# How to set constraints width using percentage instead of constants

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to add separator lines using auto layouts constraints.

[image]

The idea is to have some percent dependencies. So for example let's say that first line under first label is equal about 70 percent of superview then I need to layout second label and second line starting from 70 percent + paddings. So then second line should be less than 30% of total width.

Maybe also it's possible to do with `NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem`

The main question is how to set percentage.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the `multiplier` of a constraint is for. Set the width of the first line to be equal to the width of its superview, but with a multiplier of `0.7` (or thereabouts).

You can set that in code or in Xcode (Interface Builder).

Comment: ok got cha and then for example if I have 3 paddings left centre and right I should decrease the width using this values. let's say I have 320 width and the left padding equal 20pt then centre padding equal 5pt and right padding after second line equal 10pt. Then I should set width 320 - 35 = 285. Correct? for both lines with multiplier 0.7 and 0.3?